# WordPress post title in custom PHP application

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to pull post title of blog posts into my php based website outside of the directory I'm hosting wordpress in?

Can I use WordPress Post Title and Post Content in my PHP applications?

I have tried this one:

```
<?php
include('/wordpress/wp-load.php');
?>

<?php
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
'numberposts' => 5
));

foreach($recent_posts as $post) {
echo '<a href="', get_permalink($post['ID']), '">', $post['post_title'], 
}
?>
```

I Want to use posts on another PHP site also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why downvote, please mention results also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get WordPress title and content in custom php application.

```
<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wordpress/wp-load.php');
?>

<?php
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
'numberposts' => 10
));

echo '<ul>';
foreach($recent_posts as $post) {
echo '<li><a href="', get_permalink($post['ID']), '">', $post['post_title'], 
'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a WordPress plugin which reads all of the post titles and writes them into a separate database which can then be read by your php website.

For more information on how to create a WordPress plugin see 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I tried this and working for me.
Directly, you can include the files into your non-wp site and you can access all functionality of WordPress in your site

1) wp-config.php
2) wp-load.php

```
e.g.
include '../e-commerce/wp-load.php';
wp_head();
    <?php
$lastposts = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 3
) );

if ( $lastposts ) {
    foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) :
        setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php
    endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Hope this will helps you.